# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, indexoutofboundsexception

I am displaying data in a recyclerview. I am using Firebase Firestore. Here is how I am setting up my Adapter in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUpRecyclerView();
}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setPersistenceEnabled(true).build();
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

    Query query = db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes");


    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>().setQuery(query, Note.class).build();
    adapter = new NoteListAdapter(response, MainActivity.this);

    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new CustomRecyclerViewDivider(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, MainActivity.this);
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

And here is my Adapter:

```
public class NoteListAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteListAdapter.NoteViewHolder>{

private Context context;

public NoteListAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options, @NonNull Context context) {
    super(options);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Note note) {
    holder.title.setText(note.getTitle());
    holder.content.setText(note.getContent());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note_view, parent, false);
    return new NoteViewHolder(view);
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title, content;
    public ImageView bg_note_image;
    public RelativeLayout viewBackground, viewForeground;

    public NoteViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        content = view.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        bg_note_image = view.findViewById(R.id.note_image_view);
        viewBackground = view.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
        viewForeground = view.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(getAdapterPosition());
                Note note = snapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                String id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(getAdapterPosition()).getId();
                MainActivity.updateNote(id, note);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}}
```

So my App crashes and thats caused by this line:

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(getAdapterPosition());
```

Here's the Error:

```
09-06 21:09:11.976 19959-19959/com.test.test.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.test.test, PID: 19959
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.getSnapshot(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:70)
    at com.raycroud.notes.notes.adapter.NoteListAdapter$NoteViewHolder$1.onClick(NoteListAdapter.java:97)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5685)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22481)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getadapterposition) under getAdapterPosition() there is a Note:

```
Note that if you've called notifyDataSetChanged(), until the next layout pass, the return value of this method will be NO_POSITION.
```

So now when I don't want to crash my App I must update my OnClick in ViewHolder like this:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (getAdapterPosition() == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    return;
                }
                DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(getAdapterPosition());
                Note note = snapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                String id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(getAdapterPosition()).getId();
                MainActivity.updateNote(id, note);
                return;
            }
```

This code works and the App doesnt crash anymore. But when the error normally apears I can't click the Items anymore. I think that's logical right when you look at the code, because than the dapter position returns `-1` or `NO_POSITION`. So now is my Queston how to fix the whole Error? What I shuld do that the app won't crash **and** that I can click the Items?

Comment: Read the error: `length=10; index=-1` for some reason, it looks like `getAdapterPosition()` returns a `-1`. You can not access a negative index of an array.

Comment: This `-1` comes from [`NO_POSITION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#NO_POSITION).

Comment: @MattClark Yes, I know. So I wrote the if clause: `if (getAdapterPosition() == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    return;
                }` Then I am getting no Error such this but then I can't click the Items when normally the error appears.

Comment: And if you make `NoteViewHolder` static? I feel like that might have something to do with it.

Comment: @SUPERCILEX Than I get this: `error: modifier static not allowed here`

Comment: Oh, I thought it was an inner class, nevermind. And your items aren't updating constantly? The click listener is correct so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @SUPERCILEX Sure that works. My Items update constantly perfectly.

Comment: @SUPERCILEX I found a very bad solution: `if (getAdapterPosition() == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        ((Activity) context).finish();
                        ((Activity) context).startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                        return;
                    }` That code restarts the MainActivity when it returns `-1` or `NO_POSITION`. But it's very bad and the user can see everytime the Activity starts new :(

Comment: No, I mean do the items stop updating once they've loaded? As in is there a bug causing constant updates which would invalidate the adapter position.

Comment: Actually, hold on. I'll show how to fix this while improving your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the adapter position is being invalidated (and that should be investigated later), but you can "fix" this problem by improving your code:

1. Move `NoteViewHolder` into a separate class
2. Add a `bind(Note note, String id)` method to `NoteViewHolder` and store those values as mutable fields
3. Change the anonymous inner class to `setOnClickListener(this)` and implement the click listener in `NoteViewHolder`
4. The click listener is shown below
5. In `onBindViewHolder`, call `bind` with the note and id

`NoteViewHolder`:

```
public final class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    // ...
    private Note note;
    private String id;

    public NoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // ...

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bind(Note note, String id) {
        this.note = note;
        this.id = id;

        title.setText(note.getTitle());
        content.setText(note.getContent());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) itemView.getContext(); // You really shouldn't do this, but I don't know what you're building
        activity.updateNote(id, note);
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I am moving ViewHolder in extra class I can't call `getSnapshots()` any more. How to solve? And what do you mean by storing the values as mutable fields? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Updated. You're basically separating view binding logic from data retrieval logic. Now, all your data retrieval happens in `onBindViewHolder` where you can use `getSnapshots()`

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder`. Hence the _bind_ part 

Comment: Omg, thanks. That's so great that it works. Thanks for your help. Thank you.

Comment: One thing. Because you asked if my Items don't update constantly...How to fix this? When you don't know a solution it's okay. A lot of thanks again. 

Comment: Glad it worked! If your items are updating constantly, you'd have to make sure you aren't accidentally writing to the DB in a recursive loop. But I don't think it's that since you'd run out of the free quota super fast.